# Select Case for Access isn't working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a database in Access. This is how I set my workflow.

1. Created 'fields' table.
2. Gave each field their unique column name (ie. Project Team field has Fld10078 field ID)
3. Created 'ticket' form
4. Produced report that has a 'ticket' card looking layout with desired fields layed at desired place.
5. Each project team on the 'ticket' has their own color.

Before I came, this was already coded and was working fine. Each project team has its own unique color. I wanted to add 2 new teams with their unique colors but it's now showing up. Only the first 4 teams would show color on ticket card.

Here's the code:

```
Select Case Me.Fld10078

        Case "Team A"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(204, 0, 0)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case "Team B"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(51, 102, 255)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case "Team C"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(0, 153, 0)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case "Team D"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(255, 153, 0)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case "Team E"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(204, 0, 0)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case "Team M"
            Me.Fld10078.BackColor = RGB(0, 128, 128)
            Me.Fld10078.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Case Else
            Me.Fld10078.Visible = False
    End Select
```

Here's what I have for control source:

```
=IIf([Fld10078]="Team A","Team A",IIf([Fld10078]="Team B","Team B",IIf([Fld10078]="Team C","Team C",IIf([Fld10078]="Team D","Team D",IIf([Fld10078]="Team E","Team E",IIf([Fld10078]="Team M","Team M"))))))
```

Team E and Team M are not showing colors. They are showing text but not colors.

Comment: Please, try to understand the difference between VB.NET and VBA

Comment: If `Me.Fld10078` has a `.Text` property is that what your basing the Select Case on?

Comment: DonA, I don't know what you mean :(. This is where I have it declared if that's what you're asking. Me.Fld10078.Visible = True 
And Fld10078 isn't a text field. It's a label.

Answer (score 0):

Access can sometimes get confused if the Name of a control is the same as the database field name.

Try renaming your label Fld10078  to something else, such as TeamLabel or lblFld10078.  Use properties (F4), All tab, Name property.

**EDIT to clarify comments**

Assuming `Fld10078` is a column name, and `lblFld10078` is the label that references it, do the following:

- Set lblFld10078.Visible = True before the Select Case statement
- change the Caption property of  `lblFld10078` from the IIf statement to =[Fld10078]

Comment: I changed the name and it didn't work :(
I don't know how to resolve this now. How the heck the first four shows up and not the last two. Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Once you set the Visible property to false, you aren't resetting it to true, therefore it won't show up again.  Also, when I make Fld10078 a label, the property BackColor isn't available (testing in Access 2007).  Finally, it looks like your long IIf statement isn't necessary - because for each value, you are returning the same thing.  Simply set it to =[Fld10078].